# Перестановка найденных значений с помощью регулярного выражения в Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Возможно ли это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения в Notepad++?
Например, есть текст

> (B5+B6)C4A5
>   B1B5 C1A7
>   A7C1B1
>   C1B1A1
>   C1testB1+A7
>   C1/23*%^53B1+A2

Необходимо найденные значения (A\d*)|(B\d*)|(C\d*) привести в формат ABC, где после A будет всегда стоять B, а после B всегда будет C.

> (A5B5C4+A5B6C4)
>   A7B1C1A7B5C1
>   A7B1C1
>   A1B1C1
>   A7B1C1test+
>   /23*%^53A2B1C1+

Да, "B" может встречаться сколько угодно раз.

> Не понятно почему из `C1testB1+A7` должно получиться `A7B1C1test+`, а не `testA7B1C1+`

Потому что я редактировал ручками, и за это можно было бы не цепляться, если бы я смог редактировать захваченные группы другими группами захвата.
Нашел нечто похожее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927/how-to-use-conditionals-when-replacing-in-notepad-via-regex)

Не знаю, почему не работает (и возможно ли это вообще?) если ищу через ИЛИ(`|`).

Comment: Правила какие-то невнятные. Надо переносить `(A\d*)` и `(C\d*)` туда где `(B\d*)` стоит?

Comment: Всего существует 6 перестановок множества { A, B, C }, из них одна не нуждается в исправлении (или нуждается? не понял). Просто сделайте это за 5 подходов, а не за один, должно получиться несложно и все 5 шаблонов будут сформированы по одному принципу.

Comment: Да, можно использовать (B\d*), как для переноса A и C. Ищу через или потому что в одной строке может быть несколько B, которые необходимо дополнить A и С. Как сделать с помощью 5 заходов, если у меня 3 группы и я хочу первую группу сделать как (?1\1\2\3)?

Comment: "B" может встречаться больше двух раз? Если нет, то можно поочередно использовать ленивое и жадное выражение

Comment: Не понятно почему из `C1testB1+A7` должно получиться `A7B1C1test+`, а не `testA7B1C1+`